# Is LOAD DATA LOW_PRIORITY executed asynchronously?

Tags: java, mysql, myisam, load-data-infile

I wish to execute `LOAD DATA LOW_PRIORITY INFILE` statement from Java.

I am dealing only with MyISAM engine.

I am interested if `statement.execute("LOAD DATA LOW_PRIORITY INFILE ...")` will execute this query asynchronously, or will it block until this statement will be completed.

I am asking this since I have SQL operations after this statement that are based on the loaded data, but I am still interested that any read operation on this table that are executed concurrently will have higher priority over `LOAD DATA` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LOAD DATA LOW_PRIORITY INFILE ...` blocks until completion on the commandline, so I assume your code will block too.

If you want concurrent transactions to be able to read from your table during the import, then you want to use the `CONCURRENT` option instead of `LOW PRIORITY`.

As stated [in the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html):

> If you specify CONCURRENT with a MyISAM table that satisfies the
>   condition for concurrent inserts (that is, it contains no free blocks
>   in the middle), other threads can retrieve data from the table while
>   LOAD DATA is executing.

Comment: Thanks, i hope it blocks on LOW_PRIORITY as you answered